# PHP Wordpress upload file with local path

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress custom page where it take a path from $_GET and my idea it need to upload that file back to server. So here is my code.

customUpload.php

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_warnings', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-config.php');
  require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  header("Status: 200 All rosy");
  $wp->init();
  $wp->parse_request();
  $wp->query_posts();
  $wp->register_globals();
  $wp->send_headers();

  $getFileToPost = $_GET["noteFile"];//eg: /tmp/htmlCode/upload.html
  $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
  $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $getFileToPost, $upload_overrides );
  var_dump( $movefile );

?>
```

When ever I try with this it say file is valid .. I know its a too newbe question .. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you need to upload file in wordpress custom page ?

Comment: my idea is upload this file to wordpress server and then create a new post and add this html inside a iframe..